# How to best create a publisher aggregate of @Published values in Combine?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Given an hierarchical structure of `@OberservableObject`s - I often find myself in a situation where I need a publisher which provides some kind of updated aggregate of the entire structure (the example below calculates a sum, but it could be anything)

Below is the solution I have come up with - which kinda works, but also not... :)

Problem #1: It looks way to complicated - and I feel I am missing something...

Problem #2: It does not work as the $foo publisher on top does emit changes to foo before foo changes, which are then not present in the second self.$foo publisher (which shows the old state).

Sometimes I need the aggregate in sync with swiftUI view updates - so that I need to utilize the @Published value and no separate publisher that emits during didSet of the variable.

I did not find a good solution... So how would you guys resolve this?

```
class Foo:ObservableObject {
    @Published var bar:Int = 0
}


class Foobar:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var foo:[Foo] = []
    
    var sumPublisher:AnyPublisher<Int,Never> {
        
        // Whenever the foo array or one of the foo.bar values change
        //
        $foo
            .map { fooArray in
                Publishers.MergeMany( fooArray.map { foo in foo.$bar } )
            }
            .switchToLatest()
            
            // Calclulate a new sum by collecting and reducing all foo.bar values.
            //
            .map { [unowned self] _ in
                self.$foo // <--- in case of a foo change, this is still the unchanged foo, therefore not correct.
                    .map { fooArray -> AnyPublisher<Int,Never> in
                        Publishers.MergeMany( fooArray.map { foo in foo.$bar.first() } )
                            .collect()
                            .map { barArray -> Int in
                                barArray.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 })
                            }
                            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    }
                    .switchToLatest()
            }
            .switchToLatest()
            .removeDuplicates()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem #2 : `@Published` fire signals on "willSet" and not "didSet".
You can use this extension :

```
extension Published.Publisher {
    var didSet: AnyPublisher<Value, Never> {
        self.receive(on: RunLoop.main).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

and

```
self.$foo.didSet
   .map { _ in 
   //...//
}
```

Problem #1 :
Maybe so :

```
class Foobar:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var foo:[Foo] = []
    @Published var sum = 0
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable =
            sumPublisher
            .sink {
                self.sum = $0
            }
    }
    
    var sumPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int,Never> {
        let firstPublisher = $foo.didSet
            .flatMap {array in
                array.publisher
                    .flatMap { $0.$bar.didSet }
                    .map { _ -> [Foo] in
                        return self.foo
                    }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        let secondPublisher = $foo.didSet
            .dropFirst(1)
        return Publishers.Merge(firstPublisher, secondPublisher)
            .map { barArray -> Int in
                return barArray
                    .map {$0.bar}
                    .reduce(0, { $0 + $1 })
            }
            .removeDuplicates()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

And to test :

```
struct FooBarView: View {
    @StateObject var fooBar = Foobar()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Change list") {
                    fooBar.foo = (1 ... Int.random(in: 5 ... 9)).map { _ in Int.random(in: 1 ... 9) }.map(Foo.init)
                }
                Text(fooBar.sum.description)
                Button("Change element") {
                    let idx = Int.random(in: 0 ..< fooBar.foo.count)
                    fooBar.foo[idx].bar = Int.random(in: 1 ... 9)
                }
            }
            List(fooBar.foo, id: \.bar) { foo in
                Text(foo.bar.description)
            }
            .onAppear {
                fooBar.foo = [1, 2, 3, 8].map(Foo.init)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT :

If you really prefer to use `@Published` (the `willSet` publisher), it sends the new value of `bar` therefore you could deduce the new value of `foo` (the array) :

```
var sumPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
        let firstPublisher = $foo
            .flatMap { array in
                array.enumerated().publisher
                    .flatMap { index, value in
                        value.$bar
                            .map { (index, $0) }
                    }
                    .map { index, value -> [Foo] in
                        var newArray = array
                        newArray[index] = Foo(bar: value)
                        return newArray
                    }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        let secondPublisher = $foo
            .dropFirst(1)

        return Publishers.Merge(firstPublisher, secondPublisher)
            .map { barArray -> Int in
                barArray
                    .map { $0.bar }
                    .reduce(0, { $0 + $1 })
            }
            .removeDuplicates()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it’s not in sync with the UI updates? I will always have 1 loop delay, where the state is in transition - which isn‘t ideal.

Comment: May you explain what kind of problem you expect to have with this approach ?

Comment: If I need the aggregate to update the UI... eg. the sum could reflect the space I need to draw a result in the UI. The UI update will be triggered by the objectWillChange publisher of the ObservableObject, but the data from the publisher will only be available one cycle later?

Comment: @Michael : Ok. Leave aside the didSet extension then. I updated my answer with a new try.

Comment: @MichaelJ : did this help you?

Comment: It works - but you'd need the same amount of comments to explain how/why it's done this way - and the flatMap presents an idefinite memory leak, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

By far, the easiest approach here is to use a `struct` instead of a `class` with `@Published`:

```
struct Foo {
    var bar: Int = 0
}
```

Then you can simply create a computed property:

```
class Foobar: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var foo: [Foo] = []
    
    var sum: Int {
       foo.map(\.bar).reduce(0, +)
    }

    // ...
}
```

For SwiftUI views, you wouldn't even need to make it a Publisher - when `foo` changes, because it's `@Published`, it will cause the View to access `sum` again, which would give it the recomputed value.

If you insist on it being a Publisher, it's still easy to do, since `foo` itself changes when any of its values `Foo` change (since they are value-type `struct`s):

```
var sumPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
   self.$foo
       .map { $0.map(\.bar).reduce(0, +) }
       .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

---

Sometimes, it's not possible to change a `class` into a `struct` for whatever reason (maybe each `class` has its own life cycle that self-updates). Then you'd need to manually keep track of all the additions/removals of `Foo` objects in the array (via `willSet` or `didSet`), and subscribe to changes in their `foo.bar`.

Comment: Yep - we are having these struct vs class discussions a lot. In my real case Foo is a base class and there is a ton of other stuff going on.

Comment: Also my UI would always update at the top level… 

Comment: The top level would update whenever the array `foo` changes - as in, elements are added or removed. But, presumably, you'd want to update the sum whenever the `bar` property of an existing element changes? If so, you have to subscribe to that change.

Comment: Well if Foo was a struct then as you pointed out, a change in bar would  change the array and the entire UI would be redrawn?